# Custom metrics confusion

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, micrometer

I added https://micrometer.io to our staging server in google cloud.  The metric does not show up in "Cloud Run Revision" resource types.  It is only visible if I select "Global" as seen here...

[image]

The instructions were very simple and very clear (MUCH UNLIKE opencensus which has a way overdesigned api).  In fact, unlike opencensus, it worked out of the box except for it is not recording into "Cloud Run Revision".

I can't even choose the service_name in the filter so once I deploy to production, the metric will be recording BOTH prod and staging which is not what we want.

1. How do I debug micrometer further
2. If anyone knows offhand as well what the issue might be, that would be great as well? (though I don't mind learning micrometer and debugging it a bit more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now the only [available monitored-resource types](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#monitored_resources_for_custom_metrics) in your custom metrics are:

- **aws_ec2_instance:** Amazon EC2 instance.
- **dataflow_job:** Dataflow job.
- **gce_instance:** Compute Engine instance.
- **gke_container:** GKE container instance.
- **generic_node:** User-specified computing node.
- **generic_task:** User-defined task.
- **global:** Use this resource when no other resource type is suitable. For most use cases, generic_node or generic_task are better choices than global.
- **k8s_cluster:** Kubernetes cluster.
- **k8s_container:** Kubernetes container.
- **k8s_node:** Kubernetes node.
- **k8s_pod:** Kubernetes pod.

So, global is the correct monitored-resource type in this case, since there is not a Cloud Run monitored-resource type yet.

To identify better the metrics, you can create metric descriptors, either [Auto-creation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#md-create) or [manually](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#create-metric-desc)

Comment: ah, ok, thanks @Victor_Torres so what about reporting metrics as generic_task from cloud run.  I am trying to do that now and the metric name shows up with ZERO data.  I know that if I don't supply all the labels, it logs warnings about not writing to stackdriver.  I fixed all the warnings but no data, and then I revert to global and it works again.  Google documentation says you really should not use global but I can't get anything else to work.

Comment: not sure if the issue is in Stackdriver since with Global works fine, I was reviewing the micrometer[source code](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1003#issuecomment-556118415) in GitHub where mention updating StackdriverMeterRegistry to include the required labels for [generic_task](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#tag_generic_task).
I recommend you to open a GCP support case to discard some issue with Stackdriver monitoring API.

Comment: your post pushed me over the hill and I got it 95% there and it's reporting JVM metrics except now I am not sure if they can be used correctly.  I created a new post for this new issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728990/google-cloud-metrics-and-micrometer-jvm-reporting-is-this-a-micrometer-bug-or

Comment: Also, @Victor_Torres, posted my final code below that uses Generic Task though of course had to run into a new issue in google's aggregation of metrics in their GUI.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I have it recording all the JVM stats now but have a new post on aggregation in google's website here that seems to be a new issue...

[Google Cloud Metrics and MicroMeter JVM reporting (is this a Micrometer bug or?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728990/google-cloud-metrics-and-micrometer-jvm-reporting-is-this-a-micrometer-bug-or)

My code that did the trick was (and using revisionName is CRITICALL for not getting errors!!!)

```
        String projectId = MetadataConfig.getProjectId();
        String service = System.getenv("K_SERVICE");
        String revisionName = System.getenv("K_REVISION");
        String config = System.getenv("K_CONFIGURATION");
        String zone = MetadataConfig.getZone();

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("namespace", service);
        map.put("job", "nothing");
        map.put("task_id", revisionName);
        map.put("location", zone);

        log.info("project="+projectId+" svc="+service+" r="+revisionName+" config="+config+" zone="+zone);

        StackdriverConfig stackdriverConfig = new OurGoogleConfig(projectId, map);

        //figure out how to put in template better
        MeterRegistry googleRegistry = StackdriverMeterRegistry.builder(stackdriverConfig).build();
        Metrics.addRegistry(googleRegistry);
        //This is what would be used in Development Server
        //Metrics.addRegistry(new SimpleMeterRegistry());
        //How to expose on @backend perhaps at /@metrics

        CompositeMeterRegistry registry = Metrics.globalRegistry;
        new ClassLoaderMetrics().bindTo(registry);
        new JvmMemoryMetrics().bindTo(registry);
        new JvmGcMetrics().bindTo(registry);
        new ProcessorMetrics().bindTo(registry);
        new JvmThreadMetrics().bindTo(registry);
```

and then the config is simple...

```
private static class OurGoogleConfig implements StackdriverConfig {

    private String projectId;
    private Map<String, String> resourceLabels;

    public OurGoogleConfig(String projectId, Map<String, String> resourceLabels) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.resourceLabels = resourceLabels;
    }

    @Override
    public String projectId() {
        return projectId;
    }
    @Override
    public String get(String key) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String resourceType() {
        return "generic_task";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> resourceLabels() {
        //they call this EVERY time, so save on memory by only passing the same
        //map every time instead of re-creating it...
        return resourceLabels;
    }
};
```